# Reading from binary file in java and formatting printed text

Tags: java, file, io

I've encountered a problem that i am unable to solve so I came here.
My program has 2 tasks to do: take input from user and save to it to binary file and read the file and print the data in specific way. I am struggling with the 2nd part.

My example data is id, name, surname and birthdate:

```
1 john doe 12 01 2000
2 mark anderson 03 09 2001
3 julie cross 20 11 1999
```

I got saving covered without issues.
But i don't know how to read that data and them display it like this:

```
ID |  NAME  |  SURNAME  |  BIRTHDATE
---|--------|-----------|------------
1  | john   | doe       | 12-01-2000
2  | mark   | anderson  | 03-09-2001
3  | julie  | cross     | 20-11-1999
```

I am using DataInputStream and DataOutputStream for saving and reading the file

@Nick DeFazio as requested here is my code

```
System.out.println("Please insert the data:");
    Scanner data = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {
        DataOutputStream write= new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("database.dat",true));


        System.out.println("ID:");
        write.writeInt(Integer.parseInt(data.nextLine()));
        write.flush();
        System.out.println("Name:");
        write.writeUTF(data.nextLine());
        write.flush();
        System.out.println("Surname:");
        write.writeUTF(data.nextLine());
        write.flush();
        System.out.println("Birthdate Day:");
        write.writeInt(Integer.parseInt(data.nextLine()));
        write.flush();
        System.out.println("Birthdate Month:");
        write.writeInt(Integer.parseInt(data.nextLine()));
        write.flush();
        System.out.println("Birthdate Year:");
        write.writeInt(Integer.parseInt(data.nextLine()));
        write.flush();

        write.close();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
    }catch (IOException ex) {
    }
```

The read part that only reads first line

```
try {
        DataInputStream read = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("database.dat"));
        int id = read.readInt();
        String name = read.readUTF();
        String surname = read.readUTF();
        int dd = read.readInt();
        int mm = read.readInt();
        int yy = read.readInt();

        System.out.printf("%-4s|    %-7s|   %-10s|  %-13s%n ","id","name", "surname","birthdate");
        System.out.printf("%-3d|    %-7s|   %-10s|  %d-%d-%d",id,name,surname,dd,mm,yy);

    }catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
    }catch (IOException ex){}enter code here
```

Comment: If you got writing the file right you should be able to reverse that process and read the file into a collection of objects. Displaying that collection is just a matter of iterating over it (you can use a traditional loop or a stream) and applying the correct format to each line (e.g. using `String.format(...)`). For the column widths to be correct you might have to either make an assumption or define a maximum or iterate over the data first and collect the maximum length for each element in each column.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Or are you struggling with where to start?

Comment: @Nick DeFazio most occuring problem i had was that only last "line" of data was read. Not entire thing. The other problem was when i tried to solve it with four seperate files it still read from the last one and only the last entry

Comment: @Komin - Can you post the code you have written so far?

Comment: @Nick DeFazio I will do so when i will have access to my computer, currently i am unable to

Comment: Where's your code to read from the file?

Comment: @Alias Cartellano i am posting because i need a help with that part, because not only previous attempts were a failure but i don't know where to start now

Comment: You have no loop to read until the end of the file. Insert a [`while`](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_while_loop.asp) loop after your `DataInputStream` to read the items from the file.

Comment: @Alias Cartellano Could you write for me how this loop should look like?

Comment: Use `while(true){}` to encompass your code after the `DataInputStream`, this will exit when you hit the end of the file an throw a `EOFException`, which you will need to catch(`catch ( EOFException  eof ){}`).